# "She is at the end stage with cancer" or "She is at the last stage of cancer"

Tags: grammar, meaning, prepositions, sentence-construction, idiomatic-language

"She is at the end **stage with cancer**"

"She is at the last **stage of cancer**".

I can't be sure if **"the end stage with cancer"** is idiomatic or not. I would say **".....the stage of cancer"** rather than **"......the stage with cancer"**?

Can both be used?

Regards,

Comment: Show us your research, please.

Comment: When I search google for "stage of cancer", it produces "About 35,100,000 results", but when I search google for "stage with cancer", it only produces 23 results. This is why "stage with cancer" does not sound right to me.

Comment: stangdon has answered your question. Your problem was the "of".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of them sound very idiomatic to this US English speaker.  I would say

> She is **in** the last stages of cancer

(for some reason we often say *stages* even though I can't explain exactly why it would be plural)

or

> She has end-stage (or *final-stage*) cancer

Examples:

> [I was working with a woman who was dealing with the last stages of cancer...](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Last_Adventure_of_Life/bWsc6YWwkDQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22last%20stages%20of%20cancer%22&pg=PA89&printsec=frontcover)

> [You have final stage cancer and have just had a heart attack.](https://books.google.com/books?id=ChZUEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT252&dq=%22final%20stage%20cancer%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJ7af54q_1AhWVpnIEHaTTBh84ChDoAXoECAoQAg)

> [On behalf of all end stage cancer patients seeking life through medical breakthroughs...](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Departments_of_Labor_Health_and_Human_Se/bBlEAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22end%20stage%20cancer%22&pg=PA471&printsec=frontcover)